# How do I decrypt an AES256 bit cipher in golang that was encrypted in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, encryption, go, cryptography, aes

I encrypted a string in Node.js like this.

```
var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(
"aes256",
"<A Buffer of length 32>",
"79b67e539e7fcaefa7abf167de5c06ed"  
);
```

I noticed that a buffer in nodejs is like hex but every 2 consecutive characters are paired. So, It's length is half of whatever will come out if I convert it to a hex.

Example:

Buffer:

```
<Buffer c3 80 36 f6 51 57 cb 6d b0 e8 fd 85 5a a2 8a da 07 4b e7 19 17 d1 c8 ee dc 2a e4 d8 5e 3c 9d a6>
```

Hex:

```
c38036f65157cb6db0e8fd855aa28ada074be71917d1c8eedc2ae4d85e3c9da6
```

Now, The key I use in aes256 can not be of length 64. Here, Buffer's length is 32 and hex's length is 64.

I want to decrypt this cipher in golang and I'll have to use this key and iv to decrypt it.

aes in golang takes a length depending upon the size of key and when it sees a key of length 64 it throws an error that says, `Invalid key length`.

How do I decrypt it in golang? There is my current program in go: https://play.golang.org/p/SoXOz3XIPK

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/aes"
    "crypto/cipher"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

func main() {

    encKey := "c38036f65157cb6db0e8fd855aa28ada074be71917d1c8eedc2ae4d85e3c9da6"
    iv := "79b67e539e7fcaefa7abf167de5c06ed"
    cipherText := "c02eccfc514a0b7fae830586dd56e0fcebb81fc49f41fa6dedf099c3645793bef7ec7075eca30063f9c0ef395d5ee2d44e4f3490114280abb7cf86d6eb525e2ec9bd2b781388986480f8b3df95f7b10e"

    block, err := aes.NewCipher([]byte(encKey))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("%s", err)
    }

    decrypter := cipher.NewCFBDecrypter(block, []byte(iv))

    decrypted := make([]byte, 1000)
    decrypter.XORKeyStream(decrypted, []byte(cipherText))

    fmt.Printf("%s\n", string(decrypted))

}
```

Comment: How is this "buffer" shared between Node and Go?

Comment: @GPX It's not. A cookie is encrypted like this in nodejs and I need to decrypt it in golang so I can read data stored in it.

Comment: A cookie's value is essentially a string. What is its length?

Comment: Don't know it's exact length. But here is a program to help understand my problem. https://play.golang.org/p/SoXOz3XIPK

Comment: cipherText is cookie's Content.
encKey is the encryption Key
iv is initialization vector

Comment: @IshanJain, you should use `hex.DecodeString` in your Go program with hex values like in https://golang.org/src/crypto/cipher/example_test.go

Comment: @osgx Solved the problem. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this problem with help from @osgx

These are the things that I needed to change to decrypt correctly.

1. Decode all hex strings that I was using.
2. I checked nodejs documentation and the cipher methods/algorithms use similar naming scheme as `openssl`. So, I ran this command `openssl list-cipher-algorithms | grep "AES256"`and I got an output like this, `AES256 => AES-256-CBC` which means that, if I am using `aes256` in nodejs, It'll really be doing `aes-256-cbc`. Then I checked my golang code and I was using `aes-256-cfb` which is wrong. So, I changed that and used a cbc decrypter.

Changing these two things gives proper results.

Thank you so much for the help @osgx.

My updated code is:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/aes"
    "crypto/cipher"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"

)

func main() {

    encKey := "c38036f65157cb6db0e8fd855aa28ada074be71917d1c8eedc2ae4d85e3c9da6"
    iv := "79b67e539e7fcaefa7abf167de5c06ed"
    cipherText := "c02eccfc514a0b7fae830586dd56e0fcebb81fc49f41fa6dedf099c3645793bef7ec7075eca30063f9c0ef395d5ee2d44e4f3490114280abb7cf86d6eb525e2ec9bd2b781388986480f8b3df95f7b10e"

    encKeyDecoded, err := hex.DecodeString(encKey)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    cipherTextDecoded, err := hex.DecodeString(cipherText)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    ivDecoded, err := hex.DecodeString(iv)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    block, err := aes.NewCipher([]byte(encKeyDecoded))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    mode := cipher.NewCBCDecrypter(block, []byte(ivDecoded))

    mode.CryptBlocks([]byte(cipherTextDecoded), []byte(cipherTextDecoded))

    fmt.Println(string(cipherTextDecoded))
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Zv24WoKtBY

Comment: what was your node js equivalent code? I am facing the similar problem. Can you please share your node js code as well which is encrypting the text

Comment: @hatellla The cookies were encrypted with [client-sessions](https://npm.im/client-sessions) npm module. All the arguments were similar to one in their `basic usage` example.