# Golang Decrypt AES 256 CBC base64 from NodeJS

Tags: node.js, go, encryption

This is what I have in Node.js:

```
var crypto = require('crypto')

function encryptstring(str) {
    var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', 'NFd6N3v1nbL47FK0xpZjxZ7NY4fYpNYd', 'TestingIV1234567'),
        encrypted = cipher.update(str, 'utf-8', 'base64');
    encrypted += cipher.final('base64');
    return encrypted;
}

console.log(encryptstring("Testing 111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"))
```

That returns: `w2f0vBP2hRfgVqssqOluk68Qxkc9LXFESc0ZGzPBq3p6f/x/LbwBbg1XOoRr7I/DAtESJGdweKG6nL9m8RfewA==`

This is what I have in Go:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/aes"
    "crypto/cipher"
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
)

// decrypt from base64 to decrypted string
func decrypt(key []byte, iv []byte, cryptoText string) string {
    ciphertext, _ := base64.URLEncoding.DecodeString(cryptoText)
    block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if len(ciphertext) < aes.BlockSize {
        panic("ciphertext too short")
    }

    ciphertext = ciphertext[aes.BlockSize:]
    stream := cipher.NewCFBDecrypter(block, iv)
    stream.XORKeyStream(ciphertext, ciphertext)

    return fmt.Sprintf("%s", ciphertext)
}

func main() {
    encKey := "NFd6N3v1nbL47FK0xpZjxZ7NY4fYpNYd"
    iv := "TestingIV1234567"
    stringtodecrypt := "w2f0vBP2hRfgVqssqOluk68Qxkc9LXFESc0ZGzPBq3p6f/x/LbwBbg1XOoRr7I/DAtESJGdweKG6nL9m8RfewA=="

    stringtodecrypt = decrypt([]byte(encKey), []byte(iv), stringtodecrypt)

    fmt.Println(string(stringtodecrypt))
}
```

That ends up returning `_▒▒▒6▒▒d,O▒ob"▒`

A lot of the Go code was taken from https://gist.github.com/manishtpatel/8222606

I tried this as well: [How do I decrypt an AES256 bit cipher in golang that was encrypted in nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44498745/how-do-i-decrypt-an-aes256-bit-cipher-in-golang-that-was-encrypted-in-nodejs) (with some modifications as `hex.DecodeString` was not necessary in this case) but it would throw an error saying `panic: crypto/cipher: input not full blocks`

This was my code when I tried that:

```
func main() {
    encKey := "NFd6N3v1nbL47FK0xpZjxZ7NY4fYpNYd"
    iv := "TestingIV1234567"
    stringtodecrypt := "w2f0vBP2hRfgVqssqOluk68Qxkc9LXFESc0ZGzPBq3p6f/x/LbwBbg1XOoRr7I/DAtESJGdweKG6nL9m8RfewA=="

    block, err := aes.NewCipher([]byte(encKey))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    mode := cipher.NewCBCDecrypter(block, []byte(iv))

    mode.CryptBlocks([]byte(stringtodecrypt), []byte(stringtodecrypt))

    fmt.Println(string(stringtodecrypt))
}
```

I've searched around a lot and I can't seem to figure this out.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The first thing I see is that you're trying to decode the base64 as a `URLEncoding`, but can't be since it contains `/` characters. Have you tried `StdEncoding `?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried that and it returned: `G▒䳾6▒▒d,O▒ob"▒▒G▒{▒▒A▒zj*
ơ▒▒▒[▒▒˺`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your second attempt was closer, but you didn't decode the base64 string first.

If you go by the [`CBCDecrypter` example](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/cipher/#NewCBCDecrypter) in the cipher package, you would have something like this:

```
encKey := "NFd6N3v1nbL47FK0xpZjxZ7NY4fYpNYd"
iv := "TestingIV1234567"
ciphertext, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString("w2f0vBP2hRfgVqssqOluk68Qxkc9LXFESc0ZGzPBq3p6f/x/LbwBbg1XOoRr7I/DAtESJGdweKG6nL9m8RfewA==")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

block, err := aes.NewCipher([]byte(encKey))
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

if len(ciphertext)%aes.BlockSize != 0 {
    panic("ciphertext is not a multiple of the block size")
}

mode := cipher.NewCBCDecrypter(block, []byte(iv))
mode.CryptBlocks(ciphertext, ciphertext)

fmt.Printf("%s\n", ciphertext)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/16wV2UJ5Iw