# Nodejs / Golang aes 256 decryption

Tags: node.js, go, cryptography

I have an encrypted string that I was able to decrypt in nodejs using the following code

```
let decrypt = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc-hmac-sha1', derived, iv);
decrypt.setAutoPadding(false);
let decrypted = decrypt.update(new_buf, 'binary', 'utf8') + decrypt.final('utf8');
```

I have to be able to decrypt the same buffer in a go program and I wrote this

```
fmt.Printf("buf size=%d\n", len(derivedKey))
block, err := aes.NewCipher(derivedKey)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", err)
    return ("0")
}
fmt.Printf("block size=%d\n", block.BlockSize())
cbc := cipher.NewCBCDecrypter(block, ivKey)
fmt.Printf("cbc block size=%d\n", cbc.BlockSize())
decr := make([]byte, len(encr))
cbc.CryptBlocks(decr, []byte(encr))
```

This isn't working (I suppose I won't be posting here otherwise :p) but I also noticed that when I print the length of the derived key I get 32 but when I read the block.BlockSize() or the cbc.BlockSize() I get 16 as an answer so I'm wondering if I don't have to setup something because it is detecting my algorithm as aes128 instead of aes256.

Comment: Please fix your title spelling: when you write _ecryption_, do you mean "decryption" or "encryption"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this is working well actually, the blocksize show isn't a problem, internally it creates the correct block for the aes256, my problem was because of the parameters sent to me that added padding on the "encr" variable. But the code on top works perfectly

Comment: May I suggest, if you have an example of change, post it in your answer. As you said "a few posts... same problem". It can go a long way.

Comment: I'm sorry i'm not sure what you mean by change, i read those posts amoung others (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46475204/golang-decrypt-aes-256-cbc-base64-from-nodejs) and (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46475204/golang-decrypt-aes-256-cbc-base64-from-nodejs) but they weren't fully related to my problem, tho now i'm exploring how to remove padding. This was easy in node but in golang i can't do only a parseInt(numWithPadding, 10).toString() :D