# Decrypted value consists of unwanted characters in Go

Tags: go, encryption, cryptography, aes

I am trying to encode using JavaScript code and decryption happens in Golang.
When I decrypt using Javascript code, decrypted output is proper.
I have replicated Javascript decryption function into Golang, but when decryption happens in Golang, I see some unwanted character along with the decrypted output which I want to trim or remove.
How can I do it?

I have decryption logic written in golang.

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/aes"
    "crypto/cipher"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    encKey := "c38036f65157cb6db0e8fd855aa28ada074be71917d1c8eedc2ae4d85e3c9da6"
    iv := "79b67e539e7fcaefa7abf167de5c06ed"
    cipherText := "c02eccfc514a0b7fae830586dd56e0fcebb81fc49f41fa6dedf099c3645793bef7ec7075eca30063f9c0ef395d5ee2d44e4f3490114280abb7cf86d6eb525e2ec9bd2b781388986480f8b3df95f7b10e"

    encKeyDecoded, err := hex.DecodeString(encKey)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    cipherTextDecoded, err := hex.DecodeString(cipherText)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    ivDecoded, err := hex.DecodeString(iv)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    block, err := aes.NewCipher([]byte(encKeyDecoded))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    mode := cipher.NewCBCDecrypter(block, []byte(ivDecoded))

    mode.CryptBlocks([]byte(cipherTextDecoded), []byte(cipherTextDecoded))

    fmt.Println(string(cipherTextDecoded))
}
```

Same can be found at [text](https://go.dev/play/p/Zv24WoKtBY)
Reference thread used for decryption: [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44498745/how-do-i-decrypt-an-aes256-bit-cipher-in-golang-that-was-encrypted-in-nodejs)

Output is:

```
*▒▒?▒j-▒▒▒▒session={"user":{"email":"ishanjain28@gmail.com","username":"ishanjain28"}} *▒▒?▒j-▒▒▒▒
```

As can be seen in the output there are some extra unwanted characters which I want to remove from my decrypted output.

Comment: The extra characters at the end of the string can be explained by padding to meet block size requirements. The ones in the middle cannot be explained by that and would need the encryption code to verify.

Comment: Your own [test example](https://go.dev/play/p/Zv24WoKtBY) does not show any corruption in the middle, but only at the end.

Comment: The plaintext ends with 5 0x05 bytes (try `fmt.Println(hex.Dump(cipherTextDecoded))`). This is [PKCS#5 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS#5_and_PKCS#7). You have to strip it manually or with a third party package.

Comment: Thanks @Peter. Removal of the extra padding characters got me the exact output I was expecting. I tried removing unwanted characters from the beginning and from the end based on the length of iv and length of my decrypted text.

Comment: You still haven't explained why you are talking about a corrupted beginning, even if your example doesn't prove it.

Answer (score -1):

Passing decrypted text to below function removed my unwanted characters at the end and at the beginning of the decrypted text.

```
cipherTextDecoded = PKCS7Unpad(cipherTextDecoded, len(ivDecoded))

func PKCSUnPadding(src []byte, lenDecIv int) []byte {
length := len(src)
unpadding := int(src[length-1])
return src[lenDecIv:(length - unpadding)]
}
```

Comment: This answer is misleading. Padding affects the end of the plaintext, but not the beginning. The correct PKCS#7 unpadding is therefore `return src[:length-unpadding]`. Here you can see that with this, the ciphertext is decrypted correctly: https://go.dev/play/p/mzNmBbrVLMM. Your solution also truncates the beginning of the plaintext. This has nothing to do with what is meant by *unpadding*.

Comment: The truncation of the beginning of the plaintext can at most have functional reasons (although this does not seem plausible to me either, because after all, your solution provides an expression with one opening and two closing brackets, which seems functionally inconsistent: https://go.dev/play/p/VH4Fgi5NH_c).

Comment: You may be confusing the truncation of the first 16 bytes with the separation of IV and ciphertext in some implementations. But there the ciphertext (and not the plaintext) is separated. Quite apart from this, in your example IV and ciphertext are not concatenated at all.

Comment: Also, this doesn't check at all that the padding is valid. If the ciphertext is modified, this blindly removes an arbitrary number of bytes (<=255) from the end of the plaintext.